# How do I return a custom http status code using a spring filter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I'm trying to catch a custom auth exception thrown in the spring security flow (for an expired password, which means the user can use the current credentials to create a new password, but can't do anything else with them) and throw a http status code 419 (not part of the http spec, but easier for my clients to handle). I can't put it in a controller advice class with an ExceptionHandler because that only catches exceptions from the Rest Controller.
I'm able to catch the exception in a high precedence custom Filter, but response.setStatus(419) seems to set it to 401.

Created a custom filter implementing the filter interface, catch the custom exception thrown by the filter chain and try to change the response status

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("filtering...");
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    try {
        chain.doFilter(req, response);
    } catch (ExpiredCredentialsException e) {
        System.out.println("Expired credentials exception caught in filter");
        response.setStatus(419);
        int status = response.getStatus();
        System.out.println("status " + status);
    }
}
```

I expected it to print and return 419, but prints/returns 401. Is there something I'm doing wrong or another way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Spring Security converts exceptions to 401 by default regardless of what happens. This all from a security perspective as to not give away too much information. If you return something else a hacker knows he has a valid account but without a valid password. Or if the documentation is public he knowns how to change the password.

Comment: 419 is an authentication timeout, which doesn't give hackers any useful information.